Show or movie where a blue alien is discovered by kids in a storm drain or sewer and cuts off its own foot
My daughter is obsessed with finding out what movie or show she watched as a kid, but no googling has helped, so I'm hoping you geniuses can solve the issue!
When she describes it, it sounds a bit like a fever dream, but then it kind of rings a bell for me too, so I'm hoping someone recognises it.
Here are the memories: a blue alien is trapped in a sewer or storm drain, possibly chained up or something, and cuts of its foot to escape, but it then grows back.
In another scene, its finger gets wrapped in foil and it eats its own finger, but it grows back.
This would be a kids' film, or suitable for kids, as my daughter was probably 5 or 6 when we watched it (I think I was dozing on the sofa).
It's set in America. The main characters are kids or teenagers. I think the police get involved, but are bumbling and don't believe the kids, or some similar sci-fi trope. It was low-budget, not a big hit. I'd guess 2000s or 2010s. I wonder if it was an early Amazon Prime or Netflix show.
Any suggestions gratefully received.

This is I Was a 7th Grade Dragon Slayer (2010) AKA Adventures of a Teenage Dragon Slayer.

Branded as a "nerd" and harassed by the school bully, twelve-year-old Arthur is rescued by a magical alchemist troll who holds the secret to defeat an evil dragon, and is soon able to return the favor. Arthur's loving mom Laura, struggling to keep her devious former husband from gaining custody of Arthur, dismisses her son's "fantasies" until she realizes the real and immediate danger. She joins Arthur, the troll, the Knights of the Square Table (Arthur's pals Natalie and Tim) and a dashing fantasy card-game creator named Shane Barker. Together they hope to conquer an unleashed dragon and the wicked vice-principal who threaten civilization.

Three kids (Arthur, Natalie and Tim) discover a blue-skinned troll named Bart living in a sewer. He has a shackle around his right ankle with a broken section of chain hanging from it, as if he'd been chained up previously.


Adventures of a Teenage Dragon Slayer (2010)

He can also regenerate severed body parts. At around 33 minutes into the film, he regrows his right foot after sawing it off to get rid of the shackle. And at around 44 minutes in, he regrows his right index finger after biting it off.
The full movie is currently available to watch on YouTube, but I'll just link a trailer here. There's a shot of Bart's severed foot falling to the floor and regenerating at around the 0:57 mark.




Thank you so much! That's exactly it! Not an alien... a troll! My daughter is very grateful!
